# Angular problem: click event changes elements of other component

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a big problem with my angular project. In my website i have a lot of tables (in different sections) with fixed padding/height values for the cells. If i click on a button, the padding and heights values that i've fixed of all the tables returns to original values. Does anyone know why?
I Thank you

Comment: please attach images or minimal reproducible code. so users can get your problem easily.

Comment: Hmmm... I assume there must be some problem with your code?

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot share the code.. i know it's more difficult in this way but do you have some advice?

Comment: Before i used <span> for the button and it changed everything, instead if I use <div> it change only the values of the table belonging to other section

Comment: I imagine you are changing your padding using some like `[style.padding]="variable"`. If you use the same "variable" to all the tables, all change at time. You should use a variable that was an array -or different variables for each table-. Anyway, check, when click on button what variables changes -perhapfs you has the same name to a variable that change, and be careful if you're using template reference variable, that not match with any public variable you has in your .ts.

Comment: I don't use the same vairable for all the tables. To fix the padding or the height of the rows i simply create a class in css and set height: 30px for example.